# Не работает условие

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не срабатывает true, хотя должен. Может кто увидит ошибку в синтаксисе.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using WorldMapStrategyKit;
using Steamworks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WorldMapStrategyKitDemo {
    public class ColorIfPresident: MonoBehaviour {

        WMSK map;
        public string NCountry;
        public string defence;
        Color color1 = new Color(0.65 f, 0, 0);
        Color color2 = new Color(0.55 f, 0, 0);
        Color color3 = new Color(0.4 f, 0, 0);

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start() {
            StartCoroutine(aaaa());
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        IEnumerator aaaa() {
            map = WMSK.instance;
            for (int countryIndex = 0; countryIndex < map.countries.Length; countryIndex++) {
                NCountry = map.countries[countryIndex].name;
                using(WWW www = new WWW("http://www.go.ru/statsgo.php?c=" + NCountry)) {
                    yield return www;
                    defence = www.text;
                }
                if (defence == "1") {
                    map.ToggleCountrySurface(countryIndex, true, color1);
                    Debug.Log("Daaa");
                } else if (defence == "2") {
                    map.ToggleCountrySurface(countryIndex, true, color2);
                } else if (defence == "3") {
                    map.ToggleCountrySurface(countryIndex, true, color3);
                } else {
                    map.HideCountrySurface(countryIndex);
                }
                Debug.Log(NCountry);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

UPD Ошибки Компиляции нет.

Comment: p.s компилятор не ругается.

Comment: и что происходит после yield return www;?

Comment: В переменную defence записывается значение полученное со страницы сайта.

Comment: В чем именно ошибка? Что должно произойти и что происходит?

Comment: if (defence == "1") {
                    map.ToggleCountrySurface (countryIndex, true, color1);
                    Debug.Log ("Daaa");
                }
Вот тут нету true (как и в других условиях), хотя по факту он должен быть

Comment: Код выполняется? В `if` заходит?

Comment: Последний else в if выполняется.

Comment: Чему равно `defence`? Выведите его в `Debug.Log` или посмотрите при отладке.

Comment: defence всегда разный в зависимости от индекса страны. Сначала получаем название страны через индекс массива, далее переходим на веб страницу используя GET, она возвращает нам значение defense этой страны, и далее если значение 1>x>3 мы должны закрасить его через ToggleCountrySurface.

Comment: и зачем вам yield тогда?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html вот отсюда взял как пример.

Comment: Так  он там не нужен?